# I want to compile a C++ program with OpenCV by Boost.python to use in a python script

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost-python

First, I wrote this C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace std;

string process(string argv){
    std::string input_path = argv;

    cv::Mat input_img = cv::imread("./input/"+input_path, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    cout<<input_img.size();
    cv::Mat red_img = input_img.clone();
    red_img = cv::Scalar(0,0,255);
    cv::Mat gray_img;
    cv::Mat bin_img;
    cv::Mat diff_r;

    cv::absdiff(red_img,input_img, diff_r);

    //RGB image to Grayscale image
    cv::cvtColor(diff_r, gray_img, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    //cv::Mat diff_gray = cv::Mat(input_img.size(), CV_16U, cv::Scalar(sum(diff_r.at<cv::Vec3b>())));

    //Grayscale image to Binary image
    cv::threshold(gray_img, bin_img, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);

    cv::imwrite("./output/"+input_path, bin_img);
    return input_path;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( cv2_cpp )
{
    boost::python::def("process", process);
}
```

I want to compile this to use in Python.
Then, do this;

```
$ g++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.1_2/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/lib \
    $(python3-config --includes --ldflags --embed) `python-config --ldflags`  -lboost_python39 \
   main.cpp -o cv2_cpp.so
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::Mat()", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::Mat::~Mat()", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Scalar_<double> const&)", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::absdiff(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::imwrite(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::threshold(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int)", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
  "cv::Mat::clone() const", referenced from:
      process(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-9a3c3f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Python is ver 3.9.0 because I found Boost.python only for Python 3.9. 
In my environment, I can compile C++ program without OpenCV to .so and use in Python. 
Also, I can compile C++ with OpenCV to .out.
However, when I compile C++ program with OpenCV to .so, the error emerges.
What causes this?

Comment: I don't see you linking OpenCV anywhere, which would explain the missing symbols.